How do I properly configure a Notion API request to create a comment via Zapier's API Request interface?
I'm currently building a Zap that sends a POST request to Notion's API, however I'm getting a 400 error stating the parent/discussion_id is undefined.
{"object":"error","status":400,"code":"validation_error","message":"body failed validation. Fix one:\nbody.parent should be defined, instead was undefined.\nbody.discussion_id should be defined, instead was undefined.","request_id":"276b4121-3ec5-4ee5-b42a-4f544bf7f151"}
I've provided a screenshot of my configuration below. I'm guessing the body isn't configured correctly, but I'm having a hard time trying to get it configured correctly.
Zapier configuration
Here's the request's body as well:
{
"parent": {
"discussion_id": "183726cd-e5e5-4997-8622-7878aa5196d2"
},
"rich_text": [
{
"text": {
"content": "Test Comment"
}
}
]
}
